# how to set id to div tag using javascript/jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp

I want set ID to a `div` tag using JavaScript / jQuery.

In my project number of photo is there. Each photo have some text that will be displayed over the image using `div` tag based on x and y coordinates.

Here is my code. Are there any errors?

```
<script >

  var i=0;
  var st1=new Array();
  var st2=new Array();
  var st3=new Array();           
  var i=0;
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dimg1").hover(function() {
      for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        var X = st1[i];      
        var Y = st2[i];
        var txt = st3[i];
        var test = $("<span class='test'></span>");
        test.html(txt);
        $(this).append(test.offset({left:X,top:Y}));
      }
    }, function() {
      $('.test').remove();
    });
  });
</script>

<br><br><br>
<%

  response.getWriter().write("<div id='dimg1' class='dimg1' position: 'relative'  left:'300px'  top:'50px'  z-index: '10;'>");

%>![out put][1]
```

Comment: can you write your question in english?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the ID of HTML elements with jQuery, like this:

```
$('#id1').attr('id', 'id2');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the following

```
document.getElementById('dimg1').setAttribute('x', 'value')
```

this way you can set any attribute you want on the div